# Overflowed objects that is out of boundaries

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, flutter-dependencies

[Target Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucwMm.png)

How can i add the profile picture above the card knowing that the profile picture is on the edge of the left of the back container.

My target is to make it same as the picture provided.

[What i am upto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnV7Z.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


Widget chatCards(){

  return Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    children: [
      Container(
        width: 300,
        height: 85,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
          color: Color(0xffeeeeee),
        boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
          color: Color.fromARGB(40,21,21,21),
          blurRadius: 10,
        )]
      ),
      ),
      CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(25,150,150,150),
        maxRadius: 35,
        child: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff3600FF),
          maxRadius: 30,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: AssetImage('lib/Images/ProfilePicture.jpg'),
            maxRadius: 25,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

I tried to do it with stack and positioned widget but it ended up when I position the profile box center to be on the container ,the container disappears suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Widget chatCards() {
  SizedBox(
    width: 335, // container's width (300) + CircleAvatar's radius (35)
    height: 85,
    child: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 300,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
            color: Color(0xffeeeeee),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Color.fromARGB(40, 21, 21, 21),
                blurRadius: 10,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(25, 150, 150, 150),
            maxRadius: 35,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xff3600FF),
              maxRadius: 30,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('lib/Images/ProfilePicture.jpg'),
                maxRadius: 25,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```